# Why could this code fail?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

While reviewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461896/what-is-the-most-frequent-concurrency-issue-youve-encountered-in-java) I noticed this code:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
  private boolean stop = false;

  public void run() {
    while(!stop) {
      doSomeWork();
    }
  }

  public void setStop() {
    this.stop = true;
  }
}
```

However I don't understand why would this fail. Do other threads not get access to the "actual" stop variable?

Comment: How you are calling `setStop()` ? from same instance of MyThread or different ?

Comment: I don't know, unfortunately this is an abstract example from the question I linked to

Comment: setStop would be getting called from a different thread. all the run method has to do to stop is just return, it wouldn't need a flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instance variable `stop` needs to be volatile, otherwise there's no guarantee the other threads will see changes to it. There are a lot of conflicting interests at work: threads want a consistent view of the program state, CPUs want to be able to cache data, the JVM wants to be able to reorder instructions. Making the instance variable volatile means that it can't be cached and that happens-before relationships are established that limit instruction reordering.

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16346192/217324) (+1) for a good example of what reordering may happen without marking the variable volatile.

(By the way [using interruption for thread cancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5915306/217324) is preferable to using an instance variable.)

Comment: You should mention hoisting which is the #1 reason this can fail.

Comment: @user2246674 I created my own answer to address hoisting.

Comment: @John: is that different from instruction reordering?

Comment: @NathanHughes You're right it is.  I guess it wasn't obvious you were including that specific type of reordering.  It seemed your reasoning was more set on memory visibility and not reordering, though you did mention it.

Answer (score 6):

The JIT compiler can re-order reads and writes in an application so long as

1. the actions are sequentially consistent and
2. the altered actions do not violate intra-thread semantics.

That is just a fancy way of saying, all actions should appear to happen the same way as if it were executed by only a single thread.  So you can get the JIT to recompile your code to look like this

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
  private boolean stop = false;

  public void run() {
    if(!stop){
       while(true){

       }
    }
  }
```

This is a legal optimization called ***hoisting***.  It still acts the same as if serial but offers surprising results when using multiple threads.

By declaring a field volatile you are telling Java not to execute any re orderings. Along with the memory consistency as mentioned by Nathan Hughes

Comment: Will the JVM check to see if `doSomeWork()` ever sets the `stop` field before hoisting? I assume yes since otherwise that optimization seems not so optimal :)

Comment: @dlev Yes, absolutely!  That would result in a horrible optimization otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The variable stop must be declared as volatile.

Although i prefer using interrupt to stop a thread.

Answer (score 0):

Other threads are not guaranteed to see updated values of stop - you need to establish a "happens before" relationship. The simplest way would be to make stop volatile.